# How would this sentence be correct in English

Tags: phrases, idioms, sentence

I would like to know how a sentence, "We are looking for a suitable taxi for you" be correct, a native speaker told me it is not. I guess "for you" and "suitable" could be left out, any other suggestions?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: It is correct in terms of grammar. Is this a region/situation where some taxis are suitable and others aren't?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I take it you've never hailed a cab in New York City.  Although it's not so much the taxis that are unsuitable as the drivers.  You talkin' to me? Then who the hell else are you talking... you talking to me? Well I'm the only one here. (with apologies to Travis)

Comment: @deadrat - So the original sentence is fine is what you're saying (?). We still need to know why the native speaker said otherwise. That's why I asked.

Comment: Yes, of course.  It would be nice to know why a native speaker thought otherwise, but there are any number of reasons why "suitable" is suitable.  For instance, in NYC, the speaker might be the doorman at a hotel or apartment building who won't flag down gypsy cabs because they're illegal.